# $X$ is a random variable. $f_X(x)=2xdx$ is the density function of $X$ such that $x\in[0,1]$.$Y=\lfloor NX\rfloor$ such that $N\in \mathbb {N}$.

Tags: probability

$X$ is a random variable. $f_X(x)=2xdx$ is the density function of $X$ such that $x\in[0,1]$.

$Y=\lfloor NX\rfloor$ such that $N\in \mathbb {N}$.

For $N=2L$ , find $P(Y=L) , L \in \mathbb {N}.$

My solution :

$P(Y=L) \implies $$\lfloor 2LX\rfloor=L \implies \frac{1}{2}\leq x < 1$.

Then $P(Y=L)=\int_\frac{1}{2}^12xdx=\frac{3}{4}.$

The correct answer is $\frac{2L+1}{4L^2}$ , where am I wrong ? It looks very simple to me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there is an error in your treatment of the floor function.

$\lfloor 2LX \rfloor \neq L$ for all $X > \frac{1}{2}$

Consider $X = \frac{3}{4}$ and $L = 8$:

$$\lfloor 2 \cdot 8 \cdot \frac{3}{4} \rfloor = \lfloor 12 \rfloor \neq 8$$

Does this help you work through the rest of the solution?

Comment: $2\lfloor {LX} \rfloor \iff L \implies \lfloor {LX} \rfloor =\frac{L}{2}$ how can I solve this ?

Comment: @erez $L \leq 2 L X  < L+1$, solve for X

Answer (score 2):

$Y=L$ if and only if $2\lfloor {NX} \rfloor=L$, not $\lfloor {2NX} \rfloor=L$.